# Multi platform test on Travis-CI using Docker

Tags: docker, travis-ci, docker-in-docker

I am trying to write my `.travis.yml` to perform multi platform test on Travis-CI using Docker. The platforms I want to test on:

1. Ubuntu 14.04
2. Ubuntu 16.04
3. Debian 8
4. Debian 9

The whole concept in a nutshell is (for all 4 distros):

1. `docker pull ubuntu:trusty`
2. `docker run ubuntu:trusty`
3. Run `make test` inside the container (on my repo's clone)
4. Copy the `result.xml` back to Travis
5. Run `scp result.xml ${SERVER_USER}@${SERVER_ADDR}:/home/${SERVER_USER}/result/`

I know how to run scripts inside a docker container but how am I going to get the current branch inside the container and run `make test` on it make me go crazy.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built straight into travis. Have a look at [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/#TRAVIS_OS_NAME-environment-variable).

Secondly you should not need to specify a branch as part of your make script as travis will triggered on a specific branch and therefore that revision would already be checked out.

Comment: Travis supports only `trusty` from Linux and `osx` but I require `trusty`, `xenail`, `jessie` and `stretch`. These can only be done using docker I guess.